# How to write a filter condition when using a dataview

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a datatable  which contains all these records (see `SQL` query). Instead of writing a new stored procedure, how can I filter this condition in my datatable using dataview?

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
WHERE class = '10'
  AND Names IN ('kiran', 'manju', 'ram' , 'peter')
  AND Language = 'english'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice article how to filter data using dataview [there](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=31).

you would have to play with the [`RowFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.) property of the Dataview.

```
private void MakeDataView() 
{
    DataView view = new DataView();

    view.Table = DataSet1.Tables["Suppliers"];
    view.AllowDelete = true;
    view.AllowEdit = true;
    view.AllowNew = true;
    view.RowFilter = "City = 'Berlin'";
    view.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;
    view.Sort = "CompanyName DESC";

    // Simple-bind to a TextBox control
    Text1.DataBindings.Add("Text", view, "CompanyName");
}
```

**Note:** You have to note since the filtering and sorting would be done on client side it might perform really poorly if you have too much rows.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the SQL in your question to create a new view, you could then run other queries against that view and have that filtering done automatically:

```
CREATE VIEW MYVIEW AS 
SELECT * FROM students WHERE class='10'
  AND Names IN ('kiran', 'manju', 'ram' , 'peter')
  AND Language = 'english'
```

Comment: @kdmuray: he was talking about stocked procedure, so I suppose the view solution is not what he is looking for, I think he want client filtering